# how get all data from FirebaseFirestore before return statement

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-asynctask, google-cloud-firestore

I need a function to get all data/notes from FirebaseFirestore. 
How do I make this function wait for all data before return?

I think this function I created is not working in the main thread
and return before getting data from firebase

```java
    public static ArrayList<NoteFB> getNotes() {

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        final String TAG = "FB Adapter";

        final ArrayList<NoteFB> doFBs = new ArrayList<>();
        db.collection("notesItem")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                doFBs.add(document.toObject(NoteFB.class));
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });

        return doFBs;
    }
```

```java
        MyFBAdapter myFBAdapter = new MyFBAdapter(ShowActivity.this, FBAdapter.getNotes());

        rvContacts.setAdapter(myFBAdapter);
```

This code returns an empty ArrayList that creates an empty recyclerview.

Comment: Hi.  It looks like this code comes from a larger application; for example, what is the context of the call to `getNotes()`?  I suggest reviewing the advice on to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your question is also difficult to understand due to the way it is written.

Comment: hi @ScottMcPeak thanks for comment..
i try to make todo/notes application,
it's insert and get data from firebase,
i try to make firebase adapter like sqlite adapter but its with static functions were can use it in any place,
when i call getNotes() function its return empty arraylist,
i traced the code, i found the data come after return statement 
List from getNote() 23:43:56.028
the data from firebase 23:43:58.834 ,

how can i make function wait the all data before return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of these questions popping up lately. I had found the solution a while back : Using the Tasks API.

```
public static ArrayList<NoteFB> getNotes() {

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final String TAG = "FB Adapter";

    final ArrayList<NoteFB> doFBs = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Task<QuerySnapshot> taskResult = Tasks.await(db.collection("notesItem").get(), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
            doFBs.add(document.toObject(NoteFB.class));
         }

    } catch(Exception e) {
         Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", e.localizedString());
    }
    return doFBs
}
```

Forgive me if I made any syntax errors my Java is a little rusty.

**Make sure you are calling this code OFF the main thread, otherwise it will crash.**

Comment: Thanks very much, that's worked well with AsyncTask

Comment: Your welcome, please accept the answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface for this

```
public interface NoteDataInterface {
        void onCompleted(ArrayList<NoteFB> listNotes);
    }
```

Change your method to use interface:

```
 public static void getNotes(NoteDataInterface noteDataInterface) {

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        final String TAG = "FB Adapter";

        final ArrayList<NoteFB> doFBs = new ArrayList<>();
        db.collection("notesItem")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                doFBs.add(document.toObject(NoteFB.class));
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                       noteDataInterface.onCompleted(doFBs);
                    }
                });


    }
```

Then call your method :

```
 getNoteData(new NoteDataInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(ArrayList<NoteFB> listNotes) {
                Log.e("listNotes>>",listNotes.size()+"");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helped me too much.

Comment: Please accept it, so It can helpful to others also.